# Нужны ли кавычки? (2)

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> «Даю Вам на этот кошкопрос, — говорит Лео де Мэтр, — Леопольдовое, т. е. леопольдовское, „да“».

> «Даю Вам на этот кошкопрос, — говорит Лео де Мэтр, — Леопольдовое, т. е. леопольдовское, да».

Comment: А можно что-нибудь из классики, господин учитель? Хотелось бы изучать орфографию на примерах из литературы. Ну и стилистика вопросов очень стилизованная. Мэтр — м. 1. Учитель, наставник. 2. Почтительное наименование того, кто достиг совершенства в области науки, литературы и искусства.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Кавычки ставятся в обязательном порядке, если *да* было реально произнесено**:

*«Даю Вам на этот кошкопрос, — говорит Лео де Мэтр, — леопольдовое, т. е. леопольдовское, „да“»*.

**Кавычки не ставятся, если слово *да* заменяется на слово *согласие***:

*Даю Вам на этот кошкопрос, — говорит Лео де Мэтр, — леопольдовое, т. е. леопольдовское, да»*.

Об этом смотрите [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%C2%AB%D0%B4%D0%B0%C2%BB).

А слово *леопольдовое* с маленькой буквы нужно написать, т. к. [прямая речь «разрывается» словами автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158), а следовательно, часть прямой речи, идущей после слов автора, пишется **с маленькой буквы**.

Comment: Надо, по 166-му параграфу, писать не *леопольдовый*, а *Леопольдовый*: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=83#pp83.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Тогда _Леопольдовское_ тоже.

Comment: Если есть *-ск* — пишем с маленькой! Вниз поспотрите же-с там.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Хорошо, понял вас.

Answer (score 0):

Это от автора зависит.
Даю добро. Даю "да" (именно "да", подразумевайте "добро", "согласие").
К тому же, Леопольдовское: своё в третьем лице либо некоего третьего лица?